# Open interval $(0,1)$ with the usual topology admits a metric space

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, complete-spaces

> > which of the following is/are true ?
> >
> > 1. $(0,1)$ with the usual topology admits a metric which is  complete .
> > 2. $(0,1)$ with the usual topology admits a metric which is not  complete.
> > 3. $[0,1]$ with the usual topology admits a metric which is not complete.
> > 4. $[0,1]$ with the usual topology admits a metric which is  complete.

This question has come at my competetive exam. I think this is a wrong question, because completeness a metric space property not a topological space property.In the offical answer key, answer has given (1) and (4), I want to send my representation. So please check my representation. Thank you

Let $X = (0,1)$ and $d$ is a Euclidean  metric on $X$ which induces the usual topology on $X$ and a sequence $\{\frac{1}{n} \}$ is a cauchy sequence in the Euclidean metric , but  not converges in $X$. So $X$ is not complete withbthe usual topology admit a Euclidean metric.

On the other hand

The map
$$
f:(0,1)\to\mathbb{R}:x\mapsto\tan\pi\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)
$$
is a bijection which allows you to define the metric
$$
d(x,y)=|f(x)-f(y)|
$$
which makes $((0,1),d)$ complete. Since $f$ maps intervals to intervals then both topologies are equivalent.

So Completeness is not a topological property. So this is irrelivent.

I would be thankful, if some one check my representation

Comment: Um, the question doesn't say "complete topology"; it says "complete metric".  So there's nothing wrong with the questions.

Comment: $ 2$ and $4$ are clearly true.

Comment: The map f is irrelevant as that admits a different metric.  The questions are specifically asking about the euclidean metric.

Comment: @ fleablood :There are two metric induced the same topology and one is complete other is incomplete. So 1 and 2 are true.

Comment: In the offical answer key , answer is given 1 and 4

Comment: Should I send the representaion according to Euclidean metric.

Comment: I think it depends on what "admits" means.  Can you talk to the person who wrote the question?

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply.

Comment: On third reading I think you are right.  1,2, and 4 are correct and I think 3 is too.... if "admits" means "one can define"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42686/discussion-between-user120386-and-fleablood).

Answer (score 5):

I think it is a legit question to ask if a topological space admits a metric.

If I give you a topological space and ask you if there is a metric (with certain properties) which induces this topology there is nothing wrong about it, right? (If I got the word admit right...)

It is right that completeness may does not make sense on any space, but if I give you a space I can ask you if it makes sense. There is a broader class of spaces in which it make sense. If you are interested you can read about [uniform spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space).

Now why are 1 and 4 correct? The space in 4 is a closed subspace of a complete space ($\Bbb R$) which is complete. And for 1 you need that $(0,1)$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R$ which is complete.

Clearly to show that 2 is correct you can show that $(0,1)$ with the usual topology is not complete, just choose a Cauchy sequence which converges to $0$.

Most interesting is 3. You have to know that $[0,1]$ with any metric inducing the standard topology is complete. Here you can use the fact that any compact metric space ist complete, since compactness is clearly a topological property.

So either I got the question wrong or 2 is also correct. In the second case you can have a look at [Completely metrizable space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completely_metrizable_space) which are topological spaces whose topology is/(can be) induced by a complete metric.